# How to add the output to xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have list of arrays from which I am picking up a random one.
I can print the random output. How to pass the output as xpath value??

```
String[] Category = {"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};

    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(Category.length);
    System.out.println(Category[index]);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='\"${Category[index]}\"']")).click();
```

Comment: Try this one ? `String xpath= "//*[@name=" + Category[index] + "]"; driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
String xpath= "//*[@name='" + Category[index] + "']";   
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

Comment: thank u. But it didn't work. It shows unable to locate element.

Comment: It worked for after making this changes String xpath= "//*[@name='" + Category[index] + "']";

Answer (score 0):

It would be shorter with a CSS selector:

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(Category.length);
System.out.println(Category[index]);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='" + Category[index] + "']")).click();
```